# XlsxWriter conditional formatting does not recognize "icon_style" parameter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm currently trying to apply an icon style conditional format in excel to a Pandas dataframe output with XlsxWriter, and it has been giving me the following error:

UserWarning: Unknown parameter 'icon_style' in conditional_formatting()
  param_key

Based on the XlsxWriter documentation, this parameter is the correct way to set which icon set is used in the format.

I've found no indication for what the correct keyword is. Any idea what the current syntax is for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to upgrade your version of XlsxWriter to >= 1.0.0 where that feature was [added](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link below and scroll down to the section named `type: icon_set`. This lists a number of `icon_sets` by name, though newer versions of Excel have even more that aren't listed here. If anyone knows how to get to the icon set that has a green up triangle, the yellow minus sign, and the red down triangle, I'd prefer that to the `3_traffic_lights` or `3_arrows`.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html?highlight=icon_sets